# How to remove something from a list with recursion? Python

Tags: python, tree

I have this exercise:

You have a tree graph as input, and you need to remove its leaves. So you need to remove the empty lists from a list of lists.

For example this:

[[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]

becomes this:
[[[], []], []]

I tried to use pop and del, but the teacher said to use recursion. Also it gives None as an output. But I can't figure out how to. Can you explain it how to or can you help to solve this question?

```
  def tree_cut(tree):
  for i in range(len(tree)):
      if tree[i]=="":
          tree.pop(i)
          return tree
          for k in tree[i]=="":
              if k=="":
                  tree.remove(k)
                  return tree
```

Comment: `def remove_leaves(tree): return [remove_leaves(x) for x in tree if x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
def tree_cut(tree):
    return [tree_cut(x) for x in tree if x]
```

uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to iterate, filter and transform nodes in the tree.

Can be written also in terms of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
def tree_cut(tree):
    return list(map(tree_cut, filter(None, tree)))
```

The `if x` part [tests if the list is not empty](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

```
>>> tree = [[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]
>>> tree_cut(tree)
[[[], []], []]
```